# For loop in Python make issue

Tags: python, loops

so earlier I am learning c/c++ and use for loops intensively

```
for ( init; condition; increment ) {
   statement(s);
}
```

but now I am learning python and I came across python implementation of
for loop which is

```
for num in range(5):
 print(num)
```

My question is how for loop works in python

1.) Where is initialization?

2.) Where is testing conditions?

3.) Where is the increment?

or else python does not work like c/c++ please explain how the for loop works
in python

Comment: Have you read the docs?

Comment: There's plenty of tutorial material out there in the great web, so it's good to do your research first before asking questions here. So, it's a downvote - http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Python for loop work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292189/how-does-python-for-loop-work)

Comment: The above link asks precisely the same question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For Loop in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340130/for-loop-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to understand that [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) is not part of the for loop but is an immutable sequence type.

Range definition:

```
range(start, stop[, step])
```

> **start** The value of the start parameter (or 0 if the parameter was not
>   supplied)
>
> **stop** The value of the stop parameter
>
> **step** The value of the step parameter (or 1 if the parameter was not
>   supplied)

Python’s for statement iterates over the items of any sequence and hence since `range` is immutable sequence type what you supply to the for loop is actually a sequence of numbers.

```
>>> range(5)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> range(3, 7)
[3, 4, 5, 6]

>>> range(5, 0, -1)
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

So `range` creates a list of numbers that then the for loop is using to loop over.

You could also have:

```
for i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]:
    pass
```

and you have the same result.

Now how the for iterates over the sequence is another question. In short, it uses iterators to do this. Your best friend is to read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/) of the language you are learning.

Have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) as well there are some more examples.

Answer (score 1):

it is often recommended to use  *enumerate()*  instead of *in range()*. It
Works like this:

```
my_list = ["first_item","second_item","third_item"]
for i, item in enumerate(my_list):
    print(i)
    print(item)
```

[enter image description here][1]

Output:

```
0
first_item
1
second_item
2
third_item
```